# How can I ensure that the extension ID remains the same when publishing my browser extension for the first time on Chrome and Edge?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

if it's possible to have the same extension ID on both Chrome and Edge stores. For example, if the extension ID on Chrome is "abc", I would like the extension ID on Edge to also be "abc", rather than having a different ID like "efg" on Edge.
and I want to upload extension'zip with mainfest.json includes "key". But it show error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWwUL.png)

I would like the extension ID on Edge to also be "abc", rather than having a different ID like "efg" on Edge.

Comment: Remove `key` field and add your private key.pem file inside the zip file when you upload it.